# Event handling jQuery unclick() and unbind() events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, event-handling

I want to attach a click event to a button element and then later remove it, but I can't get `unclick()` or `unbind()` event(s) to work as expected.  In the code below, the button is `tan` colour and the click event works.

```
window.onload = init; 
function init() {
    $("#startButton").css('background-color', 'beige').click(process_click);
    $("#startButton").css('background-color', 'tan').unclick();
}
```

How can I remove events from my elements?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no such thing as `unclick()`.  Where did you get that from?

You can remove individual event handlers from an element by calling unbind:

```
$("#startButton").unbind("click", process_click);
```

If you want to remove all handlers, or you used an anonymous function as a handler, you can omit the second argument to `unbind()`:

```
$("#startButton").unbind("click");
```

Comment: http://www.visualjquery.com/1.0.4.html
unclick(fn)
Removes a bound click event from each of the matched elements. You must pass the identical function that was used in the original bind method.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I dug a little deeper, and found that unclick() was removed in jQuery 1.1.

Answer (score 6):

Or you could have a situation where you want to unbind the click function just after you use it, like I had to:

```
$('#selector').click(function(event){
    alert(1);
    $(this).unbind(event);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

unbind is your friend.

```
$("#startButton").unbind('click')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to unbind it? What if later on you want to bind it again, and again, and again? I don't like dynamic event-handling bind/unbind, since they tend to get out of hand, when called from different points of your code.

You may want to consider alternate options:

- change the button "disabled" property
- implement your logic inside "process_click" function

Just my 2 cents, not an universal solution.