# Is it possible to lock mousedown in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to lock mousedown in jQuery so it acts like the div is clicked all the time?  I have no idea where I should start.

The mousedown should be in the iframe in the background the whole time.

```css
iframe{
 width:100vw; 
 height:100vh;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 0;
}

.kram {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-style: bolder;
 font-size: 35vh;
 line-height: 30vh;
 letter-spacing: 0.02em;
 text-align: center;

 width: 80vw;
 height: 100vh;

 left: 10vw;
 right: 10vw;

 position: fixed;

 overflow: scroll;

 color: #00FFD5;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="kram">
 HALLO HALLO<br>
 HALLO HALLO<br>
 HALLO HALLO<br>
 HALLO HALLO<br>
</div>

<iframe src="https://clara.io/embed/c4b7eec0-e307-4424-a4c3-ef41d7daaf7a?renderer=webgl&timeline=false&autoplay=true&logo=false&header=false&tools=false&bgColor=FFFFFF&zoom=false"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: sounds like no good intention... for what purpose?

Comment: there is a interactive 3d element in the iframe, and it is bound to the mousedown move, its more an experiment than something concrete.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610661/cannot-fire-a-mousedown-event-with-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357819/jquery-trigger-mousedown-registered-by-addeventlistener

Comment: im still trying but i dont get it.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719001/1221332

```
$('#selector').click(function(event){
    $(this).unbind(event);
});
```